# LINQ - listview - 2 levels of data in one table

Tags: asp.net, linq, listview

I have been trying to solve this problem and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm not sure if it's because of my db design and LINQ, but I'm hoping for some direction here.

My db table:

```
Id         Name         ParentId 
1          Data1        null 
2          Data2        null 
3          Data3        null 
4          Data4        1 
5          Data5        1 
6          Data6        2 
7          Data7        2
```

Basically Data1 and Data2 are the top levels that I want to use for headings and their children will be related based on their ParentID.

I am trying to use a listview to present the data like the following:

```
Data1
-----
   Data4
   Data5

Data2
-----
   Data6
   Data7
```

I am trying to use a combination of LINQ and listview to accomplish this.

The following is the code for the linq query:

```
var query = from data in mydb.datatable
where data.ParentId == null
select data;
```

But this only gives the heading level... and unfortunately listview only takes in 1 datasource.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible with some databases (like SQL Server post 2005) to write recursive queries, I don't believe those get generated by LINQ.  On the other hand, if the number of records is sufficiently small, you could materialize the data (to a list) and write a LINQ query that uses a recursive function to generate your list.

This is from memory, but it would look something like this:

```
Func<int?,IEnumerable<data>> f = null;
f = parentId => {
    IEnumerable<data> result = from data in mydb.datatable
                               where data.ParentId = parentId
                               select data;
    return result.ToList().SelectMany(d=>f(d.Id));
};
```

That should get you the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If your hierarchy has only two levels you can use a group join and anonymous objects:

```
var query = from data in mydb.datatable.Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
            join child in mydb.datatable.Where(x => x.ParentId != null)
            on data.Id equals child.ParentId into children
            select new { data, children };
```

**Edit:** You will have to convert the data to a collection that can be bound to a ListView.  One hack would be to have a list that is only one level deep with spacing in front of the subitems:

```
var listViewItems = (from item in query.AsEnumerable()
                     let dataName = item.data.Name
                     let childNames = item.children.Select(c => "    " + c.Name)
                     from name in dataName.Concat(childNames)
                     select new ListViewItem(name)).ToArray();
```

You could also try to find a control that fits better, like a TreeView.  You might want to ask a separate question about this issue.

Comment: Thank you. It seems if I do it this way, I would not be able to bind it to a nested listview?

Comment: @user1655940: I edited my answer again.  Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote up a blog post describing a solution to build a graph from a self-referencing table with a single LINQ query to the database which might be of use. See http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Hierarchical-Trees-from-Flat-Tables-using-LINQ.